# WPF child control styling

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling

I have a UserControl which owns a button and a popup. I gave it a `ButtonStyle` property, so consumers can alter the style of the button if they like. If that's  not set, it's null, and the default button style for the application is not applied to it.

Is there any way to obtain the default button style programmatically and use it as a default? Is there some way to do that in XAML?

Comment: Set it to `null` should do the trick if `ButtonStyle` is properly bound to the button's `Style` property.

Comment: @PatriceGahide Well, I tried doing a default Style for my `UserControl` which explicitly assigns a copy of the default button style to the `ButtonStyle` property, and that works as expected. So the binding seems OK. I think.

Comment: Could just set it as the FallbackValue

Comment: @ChrisW. It's a `TemplateBinding`, which doesn't have `FallbackValue`. The control applies a template to itself. I wrote it months ago, and don't recall precisely why I made that decision. Maybe it needs to be revisited.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you have; if you set the style to `null`, it will automatically fall back to the default style, won't it?

Comment: Ah ok, I figured you had it bound in the vm or something, however if you've got it template bound via a setter that's a bit different since it's set explicitly so when it's null, the button's basically reading Style="{x:Null}" explicitly also. Will revisit this in just a bit when I have a minute more

Comment: You can probably used the `BasedOn` property of the style. For example, I know in XAML you can use `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"` to make a style inherit from the base Button style. I'm sure you could do that from code-behind too if needed

Comment: like @Rachel said that BasedOn would be a good bet, but I can't confirm it without testing since it may still accept your null as the literal value the way it is.

Comment: @Rachel Yes, I tried explicitly assigning it our default button style, which is `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"`. That's the "default button style" I mentioned assigning it in a comment above. My question is about why it is *necessary* to assign it that style explicitly, and how I can rework the control to use the default button style *implicitly* without the "user" having to do so explicitly. In practical terms, the control is unlikely ever to be used outside the context of the application I wrote it for, in our shop. I do that in the theme and we're good. But I'm curious.

Comment: @ChrisW. I think that's exactly it, in effect I'm explicitly assigning `Style={x:Null}`, which seemingly is not at all the same as just leaving the `Style` property alone.